# TypeError: Unknown file extension ".ts" in my nodeJS project

Tags: node.js, typescript, cucumber

I have a Cucumber framework running in NodeJS. The project is essentially supporting CommonJS as "type": "module" is not included inside my package.json file. Recently, some of our dependent packages have required ESM support and in order to consume these packages, we have been converting .js files to .mjs in order to use static imports. This has been successful and our tests are executing as expected.

However, when we add a .ts file (e.g. step definition file), we receive the error noted in the description. This did not occur prior to supporting ESM. I have reviewed the similar questions posted for this runtime error but, have been unsuccessful in getting them to work.